# List aggregation formatting problem

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt-list-view-web-part, aggregation

I'm a bit of a SharePoint beginner, so please forgive me if this is a very basic question.

I have a parent site with a number of identical team sites below it. The requirement is that each team site has an announcement list, and these are aggregated into a master view on the parent site.

I have had some success doing this, basically I created a new aspx page and added a data source to this containing the announcement lists from the subsites, then saved this by pushing it out as a web part to the site gallery.

The problem I have is that the body text of the announcement is surrounded by code. I thought the solution to this would be to set the 'disable-output-escaping' property to yes, but this is already set and i still have the problem.

[image: aggregate list on the sp site]

Here is what the xsl looks like at the moment:

'
    
    1
    
    0

```
<xsl:template match="/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:agg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/aggregatesource" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="($ManualRefresh = 'True')">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1"/>
                    </td>
                    <td width="1%" class="ms-vb" valign="top">
                        <img src="/_layouts/15/images/staticrefresh.gif" id="ManualRefresh" border="0" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__cancel')}" alt="Click here to refresh the dataview."/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="dvt_1">
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_StyleName">Table</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row"/>
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="RowLimit" select="10" />
    <xsl:variable name="FirstRow" select="$dvt_firstrow" />
    <xsl:variable name="LastRow">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="($FirstRow + $RowLimit - 1) &gt; $dvt_RowCount"><xsl:value-of select="$dvt_RowCount" /></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$FirstRow + $RowLimit - 1" /></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="IsEmpty" select="$dvt_RowCount = 0" />
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_IsEmpty" select="$dvt_RowCount = 0"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$dvt_IsEmpty">
            <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.empty"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
                <tr valign="top">
                    <xsl:if test="$dvt_1_automode = '1'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
                        <th class="ms-vh" width="1%" nowrap="nowrap"></th>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <th class="ms-vh" nowrap="nowrap">Title</th>
                    <th class="ms-vh" nowrap="nowrap">Modified By</th>
                    <th class="ms-vh" nowrap="nowrap">Modified</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.body">
                    <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows[position() &gt;= $FirstRow and position() &lt;= $LastRow]"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="FirstRow" select="1" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="LastRow" select="$dvt_RowCount" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </table>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.commandfooter">
        <xsl:with-param name="FirstRow" select="$FirstRow" />
        <xsl:with-param name="LastRow" select="$LastRow" />
        <xsl:with-param name="RowLimit" select="$RowLimit" />
        <xsl:with-param name="dvt_RowCount" select="$dvt_RowCount" />
        <xsl:with-param name="RealLastRow" select="number(ddwrt:NameChanged('',-100))" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.body">
    <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
    <xsl:param name="FirstRow" />
    <xsl:param name="LastRow" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
        <xsl:variable name="dvt_KeepItemsTogether" select="false()" />
        <xsl:variable name="dvt_HideGroupDetail" select="false()" />
        <xsl:if test="(position() &gt;= $FirstRow and position() &lt;= $LastRow) or $dvt_KeepItemsTogether">
            <xsl:if test="not($dvt_HideGroupDetail)" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
                <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.rowview" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.rowview">
    <tr>
        <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">ms-alternating</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$dvt_1_automode = '1'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
            <td class="ms-vb" width="1%" nowrap="nowrap">
                <span ddwrt:amkeyfield="" ddwrt:amkeyvalue="string($XPath)" ddwrt:ammode="view"></span>
            </td>
        </xsl:if>
        <td class="ms-vb">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
        </td>
        <td class="ms-vb">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Editor"/>
        </td>
        <td class="ms-vb">
            <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@Modified), 1033, 5)"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.empty">
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_ViewEmptyText">There are no items to show in this view.</xsl:variable>
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-vb">
                <xsl:value-of select="$dvt_ViewEmptyText"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.commandfooter">
    <xsl:param name="FirstRow" />
    <xsl:param name="LastRow" />
    <xsl:param name="RowLimit" />
    <xsl:param name="dvt_RowCount" />
    <xsl:param name="RealLastRow" />
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <xsl:if test="$FirstRow &gt; 1 or $LastRow &lt; $dvt_RowCount">
                <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.navigation">
                    <xsl:with-param name="FirstRow" select="$FirstRow" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="LastRow" select="$LastRow" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="RowLimit" select="$RowLimit" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="dvt_RowCount" select="$dvt_RowCount" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="RealLastRow" select="$RealLastRow" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.navigation">
    <xsl:param name="FirstRow" />
    <xsl:param name="LastRow" />
    <xsl:param name="RowLimit" />
    <xsl:param name="dvt_RowCount" />
    <xsl:param name="RealLastRow" />
    <xsl:variable name="PrevRow">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$FirstRow - $RowLimit &lt; 1">1</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$FirstRow - $RowLimit" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="LastRowValue">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$LastRow &gt; $RealLastRow">
                <xsl:value-of select="$LastRow"></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$RealLastRow"></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="NextRow">
        <xsl:value-of select="$LastRowValue + 1"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:variable>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" class="ms-paging" align="right">
        <xsl:if test="$dvt_firstrow &gt; 1" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
            <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">javascript: <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('dvt_firstrow={1}')" />;</xsl:attribute>
            Start</a>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
            <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">javascript: <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('dvt_firstrow={',$PrevRow,'}'))" />;</xsl:attribute>
            <img src="/_layouts/15/images/prev.gif" border="0" alt="Previous" />
            </a>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="$FirstRow" />
         - <xsl:value-of select="$LastRowValue" />
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="$LastRowValue &lt; $dvt_RowCount or string-length($dvt_nextpagedata)!=0" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
            <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">javascript: <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('dvt_firstrow={',$NextRow,'}'))" />;</xsl:attribute>
            <img src="/_layouts/15/images/next.gif" border="0" alt="Next" />
            </a>
        </xsl:if>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

Any advice or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="@Editor"/>
```

for:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Editor.title"/>
```

It works the same with Author(Created by)

And also you can get more properties, if you click in "`Data source details`" in the `options` tab of your SharePoint Designer, you can see all properties from your item:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Thales :) That helpded a lot, and fixed the problem with that field.  Now I have added 'Body' for the body text of the list items, but this either displays with the code around it, and if I add '.title' to the body field in the same way, it just disappears.

Any idea what I would have to add to this line to get it to display correctly?

<xsl:value-of select="@Body" /></td><td class="ms-vb">

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Wich type of data are you using for your column named body?

Comment: Hmm I'm not too sure. i can view data source details and get the list as you show above, it does list the body field, but I can't see any option to view field properties. All that's in the source list fields is plain text data.

Comment: In this case try to add disable-output-escaping="yes" in your xsl:value-of

Comment: That did it!! I had to play around as I'm not familiar with the syntax, but basically this row did the trick -
`<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="@Body"/>`
Thank you for your help Thales :)